# database connection in shell script failed when execute from cron

Tags: bash, shell, cron, db2

I wrote a script which get & backup the file from other server, and it works
when executing it from console, but it fails when executing from cron.

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# working directory
dir_work="somedir/work"

# backup directory
dir_bkup="somedir/bkup"

# db2 setting
. $HOME/sqllib/db2profile

# Get file by using SCP
getFilebyScp(){
    scp -i KEY -p user@10.0.0.1:"$download_file" "$dir_work"
RC=$?
    if [ $RC -ne 0 ]; then
      { echo 'Cannot get the file...'; exit $RC; }
    fi
}

# Processing Start
echo 'START'

# DB Connection
db2 connect to DATABASE user USERNAME using PASSWORD || { echo "database connection failed."; exit 1; }

# assign file_information to an array
file_info="($(db2 -x -t "select status, file_path from SOME_TABLE \
                where id = 999 \
                and status = 2 \
                and entry_id = (select max(entry_id) from SOME_TABLE where id = 999)"))"
                
download_file="${file_info[1]}"

# check the status of file 
if [ "${file_info[0]}" -eq 2 ]; then
  getFilebyScp
elif [ "${file_info[0]}" -eq 1 ]; then
  { echo 'Skip the process because output if the file is not finished yet.'; exit 1; }
else
  { echo 'Skip the process because some error happen in output file.'; exit 1; }
fi

new_file="$(basename "${download_file// /_}")"
mv -f "$download_file" "$new_file"

bkup_file=${new_file%%.csv}'_'$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).csv
mv -f "${new_file}" "${dir_bkup}"/"${bkup_file}" || { 'Backup failed...'; exit 1; }

echo 'END'
```

and crontab is like this.

```
15 17 * * * /bin/bash -l /somedir/otherdir/myscript.sh > crontab.log
```

what's wrong with that?

**additional note**

- user account of script and crontab's account is same.
- DB2 instance name is db2inst1
- Operating system is RHEL(version is unknown).

[SOLVED]

I found `$()` command is executed as sub shell, so initial connection is not available in the sub shell. so I fixed the script like below.

```
#!/bin/bash

# working directory
dir_work="somedir/work"

# backup directory
dir_bkup="somedir/bkup"

# db2 setting
. $HOME/sqllib/db2profile

# Get file by using SCP
getFilebyScp(){
    scp -i KEY -p user@10.0.0.1:"$download_file" "$dir_work"
RC=$?
    if [ $RC -ne 0 ]; then
      { echo 'Cannot get the file...'; exit $RC; }
    fi
}

# Processing Start
echo 'START'

# DB Connection
db2 connect to DATABASE user USERNAME using PASSWORD || { echo "database connection failed."; exit 1; }

# assign file_informations
db2 -txf "/somedir/otherdir/status.sql" > "$dir_work"/status
db2 -txf "/somedir/otherdir/path.sql" > "$dir_work"/path
original_file_status=$(cat "$dir_work/status")
original_file_path=$(cat "$dir_work/path")

download_file="${original_file_path}"

# check the status of file 
if [ "$original_file_status" -eq 2 ]; then
  getFilebyScp
elif [ "$original_file_status" -eq 1 ]; then
  { echo 'Skip the process because output if the file is not finished yet.'; exit 1; }
else
  { echo 'Skip the process because some error happen in output file.'; exit 1; }
fi

new_file="$(basename "${download_file// /_}")"
mv -f "$download_file" "$new_file"

bkup_file=${new_file%%.csv}'_'$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).csv
mv -f "${new_file}" "${dir_bkup}"/"${bkup_file}" || { 'Backup failed...'; exit 1; }

echo 'END'
```

I split elements in the array into two variables, and assigned each variables by using two SQL files.

Thank you for comments!

Comment: Can you see if `$HOME` is accessible when running from `cron`? I am sure there is a user specific path which `HOME` uses, which _might_ not be accessible when using cron

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Can you give some `error trace`? Either maybe cron cannot get right value of `$HOME` or some command cannot work well as normal, try to use `eval()`!

Comment: `$HOME` is accessible from cron, and I debugged this script by using `bash -x ./myscript.sh`, and it shows db connection is success, but when executing SQL, it says "SQL1024N A database connection does not exist. SQLSTATE=08003".

Comment: Edit your question to add missing facts: (1)   *which* crontab (of which user-account) are you using ?, (2) Which is your Db2 instance name, because I would expect to see that name in the path for the db2profile for example : `. ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile` and (3) which operating-system detail is running bash (cygwin?, bash under Windows-10, which linux distro/version) ?

Comment: Which line of code throws the SQL1024N?  If it is the line that initializes the array, then try splitting it up, first line collects the output, second line initializes the array like this: `cmdout=$(db2 -x -t "select..." )` followed by an error-check, followed by `declare -a file_info="(${cmdout})"` .  To find the RHEL version `cat /etc/redhat-release` and `lsb_release -a`

Comment: the line which throws error is `file_info="($(db2 -x -t "select status, file_path from SOME_TABLE \
                where id = 999 \
                and status = 2 \
                and entry_id = (select max(entry_id) from SOME_TABLE where id = 999)"))"`. I fix script try not to use array and it works. I'll re-edit the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$()` command is executed as a sub shell, so the initial connection is not available in the sub shell. so I fixed the script like below.

```
#!/bin/bash

# working directory
dir_work="somedir/work"

# backup directory
dir_bkup="somedir/bkup"

# db2 setting
. $HOME/sqllib/db2profile

# Get file by using SCP
getFilebyScp(){
    scp -i KEY -p user@10.0.0.1:"$download_file" "$dir_work"
RC=$?
    if [ $RC -ne 0 ]; then
      { echo 'Cannot get the file...'; exit $RC; }
    fi
}

# Processing Start
echo 'START'

# DB Connection
db2 connect to DATABASE user USERNAME using PASSWORD || { echo "database connection failed."; exit 1; }

# assign file_informations
db2 -txf "/somedir/otherdir/status.sql" > "$dir_work"/status
db2 -txf "/somedir/otherdir/path.sql" > "$dir_work"/path
original_file_status=$(cat "$dir_work/status")
original_file_path=$(cat "$dir_work/path")

download_file="${original_file_path}"

# check the status of file 
if [ "$original_file_status" -eq 2 ]; then
  getFilebyScp
elif [ "$original_file_status" -eq 1 ]; then
  { echo 'Skip the process because output if the file is not finished yet.'; exit 1; }
else
  { echo 'Skip the process because some error happens in the output file.'; exit 1; }
fi

new_file="$(basename "${download_file// /_}")"
mv -f "$download_file" "$new_file"

bkup_file=${new_file%%.csv}'_'$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).csv
mv -f "${new_file}" "${dir_bkup}"/"${bkup_file}" || { 'Backup failed...'; exit 1; }

echo 'END'
```

I split elements in the array into two variables and assigned each variable by using two SQL files.